# Deleting row from database if value =? in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have 2 separate SQL tables in the same `.db` file. This is using SQLite.

**table 1**

```
column1   column2
ggg       values
ttt       values
yyy       values
hhh       values
ddd       values
jjj       values
```

**table 2**

```
column1   column2   column3    column4
ggg       values    s_values     words
zzz       values    s_values     words
aaa       values    s_values     words
qqq       values    s_values     words
hyh       values    s_values     words
jjj       values    s_values     words
```

Using table 1 as the base, if table 2 has items from table 1, how do I delete the entire row in table 2?

```
test1 = pandas.read_sql_table('table 1', con=engine)['column1']
test2 = pandas.read_sql_table('table 2', con=engine)['column1']

for each_item in test1:
    if each_item in test2['column1'].unique():
        connection.execute('DELETE FROM "table2" WHERE column1=?', column1=each_item)
```

I have read most of the posts on stackoverflow and checked the documentations regarding this, but I'm still getting errors to deleting `row` in `table2`.

Comment: pandas seems somewhat overkill for this... can't you just execute `delete from table2 where column1 in (select column1 from table1)` directly on the connection?

Comment: @JonClements It's still showing me that an error message saying that `This Connection is closed`

Comment: I'd suggest using it when it's open then? :)

Comment: @JonClements sigh... i feel so stupid... thanks Jon.. lol

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jon CLements, I realized my mistake of not opening the engine.. Thus getting errors for it. :(